# How to look up (or match) two criteria and then average any value that matches those two criteria

Tags: google-sheets, average, lookup, gs-vlookup

I have two sheets.

On sheet #1, column A is made up of publishers (publisher 1, publisher 2, publisher 3, etc.), and row 1 is made up of topics (topic 1, topic 2, topic 3, etc.).

On sheet #2, column D lists the publishers, and column F lists the topics in random order. Lastly, column H holds the sentiment score for each corresponding publisher's topic.

I need to get the average sentiment score for each topic per publisher. Here's a sample worksheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IY-Ev0OWR8z2qeDzTxWEFSKFJVP8JYZyEhrzhFwUWnA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misunderstood. Try this in cell B2.

```
=iferror(average(filter('Sentiment per URL'!$H$2:$H, ('Sentiment per URL'!$D$2:$D=$A2)*('Sentiment per URL'!$F$2:$F=B$1))))
```

then drag this formula to the right and down as far as needed.
See if that works ?

Comment: It works! Thank you, JPV! You saved me a few hours of tedious labor!

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
=query('Sentiment per URL'!D1:H, "Select D, F, AVG(H) where D <> '' group by D, F ",1)
```

Comment: No luck. For starters, there's already some data in the cells as shown in the sample worksheet. Running your formula didn't work with existing data  in the sheet. When I removed the data, it did produce results, but not exactly what I desire.

Comment: For example, I want to see the average score for topic 2 for each publisher. Then average score for topic 3 for each publisher, and so on.